# How to set a default value on a dropdown php filter

Tags: php, filter, default

I have this code:

```
<div class="styled-select">
        <?php $filters = get_projects_filters(); ?>
        <select class="about-projects-filter-year">
            <option value="">Todos os Anos</option>
                    <?php foreach ($filters["year"] as $ano): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $ano ?>"><?php echo $ano ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

I wanna set the current year as default selected value, but all codes I try fail.

Some code even make 2016 selected but the actually filter doesn't work, it keeps filtering All Years ("Todos os Anos").

How can i solve it?

Comment: in the foreach set the option as `selected=selected` for the current year

Answer (score 2):

```
<option value="<?php echo $ano ?>" <?php if($ano == date("Y")){ echo "selected" } ?>><?php echo $ano ?></option>
```

Using the if statement to compare with the current date("Y") will mark selected if the $ano is equal to the current year.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @aallord, but didn't work.

As soons as I put the code the page will return error 500, This page is not working.

Comment: Error 500 isn't referring to the code above, it is in the main PHP file and something isn't coded right... Look at your get_project_filters() function.

Comment: Sorry to be so begginer in codding, but I dont know what to look =/
This is the function code for this filter that i was able to find... Can you see what could be wrong?

function get_projects_filters() {
  $filters = array("year" => array(), "state" => array());

  $post = array_pop(get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'projetos-apoiados' ) ));
  
  $ano_field = get_field_object(array_pop(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_ano')));
  $estado_field = get_field_object(array_pop(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_uf')));

  return array("year" => $ano_field["choices"], "state" => $estado_field["choices"]);
 }

Comment: I looked at your code above and it is also referencing other functions that aren't there. Actually not enough information for me to visualize what is actually happening within your code.